# Logging Zigbee network statistic

Tags: zigbee

Is there any zigbee cluster (or others zigbee methods) that we can use to for network statistic?

I will need to log inside the coordinator all the link quality/pattern and the signals strength of the zigbee network.

Comment: Sorry, not really answering your question but was curious to know if you did figure this out and if so what/how did you do? Am looking to do something similar and was interested in knowing if you got any updates since posting the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `Mgmt_Lqi_req` from the ZDP (if your stack supports this) and collect the data from all FFD devices. As you can see in the Specification the response contains the LQI value for each 1 hop neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Freakduino](http://www.freaklabsstore.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=187) to [sniff 802.15.4 traffic](http://hackaday.com/2010/12/29/bringing-the-shark-to-the-bee/) for later analysis with wireshark. 
At this moment, only the 2.4GHz version of the Freakduino is available, though a 900MHz version is in progress, so only 2.4GHz networks can be sniffed.